# 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)

Tags: node.js, typescript

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function(done) {
    if (this.isModified('pass')) {
        const hashed = await Password.toHash(this.get('pass'));
        this.set('pass', hashed);
    }
    done();
});
```

I am getting the following error from "this":

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type
>   annotation.ts(2683)

I heard the problem came from the arrow key, but I am not using an arrow key for the callback function? I am still getting an error. What gives?

I am also getting an error from "done":

> Parameter 'done' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

Could it be some kind of bug with Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing the following, i've had this same issue and I worked around like so...

```
// We generally explicitly provide a type to the arguments we are using...

userSchema.pre('save', async function(done: any) {
    const self: any = this;

    if (this.isModified('pass')) {
        const hashed = await Password.toHash(self.get('pass'));
        self.set('pass', hashed);
    }
    done();
});
```

From what I've come to understand, the error seeds from the typescript config which can be modified for implicit typings in order to not show the error.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a bug in VS Code or in TypeScript. It is simply that there is not enough information from the call for TypeScript to determine what `this` will be bound to when the function is ultimately executed by Mongoose.

Assuming you have a type called `User`, you can fix this with an explicit `this` type annotation.

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function(this: User, done) {
    if (this.isModified('pass')) {
        const hashed = await Password.toHash(this.get('pass'));
        this.set('pass', hashed);
    }
    done();
});
```

Note that the syntax used to specify the type of `this`, is a special syntax in that it does not emit a parameter in the resulting JavaScript:

```
function(this: X) {}
```

compiles to

```
function() {}
```